# Blazor events don't trigger on duplicate instances of a component

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, jquery-select2, blazor-server-side

I have created a wrapper around [Select2](https://select2.org/) so that I can create Tag controls in my app:

[image: Implementation of Tag component]

However, I have noticed that events that trigger when a new tag is added are not firing as I'd expect:

##### Expected Behavior

1. Set *Order Number* to `O1234`
2. SelectedValuesChanged fires from component passing `O1234`
3. Set *Customer Order Number* `CO1234`
4. SelectedValuesChanged fires from component passing `CO1234`

##### Actual Behavior

1. Set *Order Number* to `O1234`
2. SelectedValuesChanged fires from component passing `O1234`
3. Set *Customer Order Number* `CO1234`
4. No event fires.

#### The Components

```cs
// The Select2TagSelect component
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@namespace BillOfLading.UI.Web.Components.Shared

@using Microsoft.JSInterop

<select id="@ElementId" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple"></select>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string ElementId { get; set; } = "select2_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

    [Parameter]
    public IList<string> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IList<string>> SelectedValuesChanged { get; set; }

    private DotNetObjectReference<Select2TagSelect>? objRef;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    }

    private async Task OnSelectionChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        SelectedValues = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IList<string>>("select2InteropTag.getSelectedValues", ElementId);
        await SelectedValuesChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedValues);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("select2InteropTag.initializeSelect2Tag", objRef, ElementId);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async void SetSelectedText(IList<string> selected)
    {

        SelectedValues = selected;
        await SelectedValuesChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedValues);
    }

}
```

```js
// Interop javascript loaded on the page
window.select2InteropTag = {
    initializeSelect2Tag: function (dotNetHelper, elementId) {
        $('#' + elementId).select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
        }).on('change', (event) => {
            console.log("Element " + elementId + " has changed");
            var data = $('#' + elementId).select2('data');
            if (data) {
                var value = data.map((element) => element.text);
                dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SetSelectedText', value);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

```
// Page rendering the Tab controls

<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-2 col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <label class="form-label">Order Number(s)</label>
        <Select2TagSelect ElementId="@($"select2-orders-{ShortGuidGenerator.ShortGuid()}")" SelectedValuesChanged="ChangeOrders"></Select2TagSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2 col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <label class="form-label">Customer Order Number(s)</label>
        <Select2TagSelect ElementId="@($"select2-customerOrders-{ShortGuidGenerator.ShortGuid()}")" SelectedValuesChanged="ChangeCustomerOrders"></Select2TagSelect>
    </div>
</div>

//... snip ...

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public BillPropertiesViewModel Model { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<BillPropertiesViewModel> ModelChanged { get; set; }

    private void ChangeOrders(IList<string> obj)
    {
        Model.Orders = obj;
        ModelChanged.InvokeAsync(Model);
    }

    private void ChangeCustomerOrders(IList<string> obj)
    {
        Model.CustomerOrders = obj;
        ModelChanged.InvokeAsync(Model);
    }
}
```

What is peculiar is that the javascript console shows events on both controls are firing (ex: "Element xyz has changed"), but it's like the interop between javascript and the C# blazor code isn't working.

##### What I've Tried

I've removed the `firstRender` check from `OnAfterRenderAsync`. That definitely gets both components to trigger their events. However, if I look at my logs of the events I see now they're duplicating (because the javascript event registration is getting called every time the component re-renders). This could cause significant performance problems so I don't like it as a solution.

I'm wondering if I need to use `@ref` or something to help blazor keep better track of objects? I'm not sure...

Any thoughts on why this behavior is occurring?

Comment: Is `ShortGuidGenerator.ShortGuid()` generating a new guid each time the page renders?

Comment: This pretty specific.  *Select2* is not mainstream Blazor, is JS and uses JQuery, so it's likely to modify [in reality corrupt] the DOM that Blazor manages.  That will cause conflicts that are difficult/impossible to resolve.  You're probably flying solo here!

Comment: @MisterMagoo: I think you're right! That might be the reason for a separate, but related bug.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis: You're right in that this is pretty specific; however, I am trying to only modify the DOM via interop calls, which I thought Blazor supported? Select2 is a very popular library and I can't seem to get third-party controls (MudBlazor, FluentUI) to style or behave in the same way....

Comment: My honest opinion: rewrite this as a Blazor component. There is no reason to rely on JavaScript. This is an easy component to write in Blazor. 1 select with `@onchange` that populates a `List<T>` and renders the results in an element.

Comment: @Marius yes, I think that's probably a good plan and something to look into as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use custom generated element IDs, use Blazor's `ElementReference`.

If passed to JavaScript through `IJSRuntime`, the element will be passed as a reference, so you don't need to get the element via some ID or other logic. Which is what is most likely causing your issue.

You will have to replace code to look like this:

Component:

```
<select @ref="@selectReference" ... />

@code {
    ...
    ElementReference selectReference;
    ...

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("select2InteropTag.initializeSelect2Tag", objRef, selectReference);
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.select2InteropTag = {
    initializeSelect2Tag: function (dotNetHelper, element) {
        element.select2({
            ...
        }).on('change', (event) => {
            var data = element.select2('data');
            ...
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried to apply this but it didn't seem to work. The function `select2` wasn't available directly on the `element` object in javascript. However, I do believe I got my issue resolved and it was related to @MrMagoo's comment on regenerating the ElementId each time the component rendered (which would then change the ElementId from what was initially subscribed within javascript)

Comment: You probably just need to change `element.select2` to something like `$(element).select2`. Did you play around with the call? Using `ElementReference` is the correct way to handle this.